# Resquest based on date in Teradata

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

i have a table in Teradata with a field CREATION_TS as timestamp like "2023-04-24 11:49:51.07"

i would like to retrieve all the rowss that match the day of the most recent date

i tried something like
select CAST(count(*) as BIGINT) from  mytable where CREATION_TS >= ( select max(CREATION_TS)-1 from mytable) ;

i tried also to convert to datetime with date(max(creation_ts)) or extract(creation_TS, Day)...

i got always an "invalid operation on dattetime when i try to substract -1 to creation_ts or (max(creation_ts))

Anyone can help ?

i search on google i tried several examples

Comment: Timestamp require INTERVAL syntax. How do you define *most recent date*? Within the last 24 hours of the max date? `where CREATION_TS >= ( select max(CREATION_TS)- interval '1' day from mytable)`. Same day as the max date? `where CREATION_TS = ( select cast(max(CREATION_TS) as date) from mytable)`